# CSS: text is not visible

Tags: css

We have CSS `.block.block-dark h2 {color: #ffba0d;}` but both the h2 & p are invisible below.

The div they are in has a higher `z-index` than the div preceding them that has the background color (`<div class="column-overlay block-dark" style="opacity: 90%"> </div>`).

I can't see why the background color is displaying over the top of the div with the text in it.

Help appreciated.

```css
.column-bg-img {background-image: url('http://mercury.herodevelopment.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Mercury_Residential_Air_Conditioning.jpg');}
.block .block-background-image.bg-scroll {
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
.block .block-background-image {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.block .block-background-image, .block-overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
.columns_block .column-bg-img, .columns_block .column-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.columns_block .column-overlay.block-dark {
    background-color: #2d3133;
}
.block.block-dark h2, .block.block-white h2, .carousel_block .carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item .carousel-caption .carousel-caption-inner h3 {
    color: #ffba0d;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.col-xl {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper block columns_block block-dark">
  <div class="block-overlay" style="opacity: 90%"></div>
  
  <!-- columns-block.twig -->
  <div class="block-background-image bg-scroll" style="background-image: url('');"></div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" data-scroll="in">
      <div class="col-12 col-xl">
        <div class="column-bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://mercury.herodevelopment.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Mercury_Residential_Air_Conditioning.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="column-overlay block-dark" style="opacity: 90%"> </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h2 style="text-align: center;">Residential</h2>
          <p style="text-align: center;">We’ve been installing, servicing, and repairing air conditioning systems in people’s homes for decades.<br>
            Our experience and expertise allows us to offer the ideal air conditioning system for you</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-xl">
        <div class="column-bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://mercury.herodevelopment.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Mercury_Commercial_Air_Conditioning.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="column-overlay block-dark" style="opacity: 90%"> </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h2 style="text-align: center;">Commercial</h2>
          <p style="text-align: center;">We install air conditioners for commercial and industrial buildings,<br>
            and are able to offer systems tailored to the exact needs of your business.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the `<div>` element holding the text don't have `z-index` property where the `<div>` element holding background has `z-index:0` property. Try adding this css rule.

```
.column {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the

```
.columns_block .column-bg-img, .columns_block .column-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Change your z-index to be **z-index:-999;**
this should fix your issue.

so the solution to your code is :

```
.columns_block .column-bg-img, .columns_block .column-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -999;
}
```

Explanation: the default z-index for all elements is 0, if you did not put a z-index for the elements inside your overlay(ed) div, then they will also assume z-index:0 which is what is currently hiding your elements. Either put a higher z-index to your h2 , p tags or reduce the z-index of your background overlay to be in the negative range(-999).

Comment: Divs with negative z-indexs do not display in Safari on Mac.